# CSS hover animation works codesandbox (React), but breaks when implemented in Next.js project

Tags: css, animation, next.js

**Problem**

[In codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4th-2fbjwp?file=/src/ShadowTilesLis.jsx) I built a hover animation for a div-element. I used the working code on a li-element in my next.js project, but after copying over the code the hover-effect isn't triggered on hover, but on click instead. Plus: The element stays stuck in the hovering position, until the next click is exerted. Weird?

Recorded a little video --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IV7PIvmpzX8

What could be the problem?

The relevant code for this page:

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import styled from "styled-components";

console.clear();

const StyledUl = styled.ul`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 30px;
  padding: 0px 50px;
`;
const StyledLi = styled.li`
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;

  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 1px 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  &:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
  }
`;
const StyledP = styled.p`
  font-size: var(--fontsize_pageText);
`;

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <StyledUl>
      <StyledLi>
        <StyledP>something</StyledP>
      </StyledLi>
      <StyledLi>
        <StyledP>something</StyledP>
      </StyledLi>
      <StyledLi>
        <StyledP>something</StyledP>
      </StyledLi>
      <StyledLi>
        <StyledP>something</StyledP>
      </StyledLi>
    </StyledUl>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is normal, when you are in tablet/mobile mode on every browser the browser switches from an usual cursor to an emulated touch cursor which replaces the usual desktop browser events with [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

In Chrome you can change that using their tools like it's shown in their [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/#type)